# socket tcp in visual basic 4 - 16 bits . Winsock or similar

Tags: sockets, tcp, vb6

i'm creating a program in visual basic 4 - 16 bits version. I will need to use socket tcp. In later version of visual basic i used winsock but in 16 bits no encounter any socket or reference about winsock.

I would like to be able to use a socket Winsock or similar for commnications. Thanks

**Finally I have solved it with Delphi7**. Using the TddeClientItem components and the own delphi socket. VB6 does not work on the machine, but Delphi7 does work.

Thanks for your help

Comment: I'm pretty sure we always used either a 3rd party TCP/IP stack or something piggybacking on the old DOS TCP/IP stack, with a 3rd party VBX on top of that in 16-bit VB.  Finding info on this now may be tough enough, let alone finding the software bits.

Comment: You may also want to see if the [Retrocomputing.se] site can help. 16-bit Windows APIs are pretty "retro" now.

Comment: I remember using the old 3rd party 16-bit SocketWrench library from Catalyst Development and a similar package from Dart.  No idea whether they still offer 16-bit libraries though.